# SQL Insert calculated average value from another table

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I tried to insert a calculated average from a table to another table writing the sql like below but it didnt work. Can someone please help me out ? how can I write it like a stored procedure in Oracle to cater for many states i.e. `CA, IL, GA, WI`.... ?

```
 INSERT INTO Employee(averageSalary, averageTax)
  (SELECT AVG(Salary), AVG(Tax)
   FROM HrDeptEmployee 
   WHERE State = 'NY')
```

Comment: Leave off the parentheses around the select, this is not a subselect.

Comment: You should post it as an answer @FrankPl

Comment: @FrankPI I got this error. `SQL Error: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("AbbotLTD"."Employee"."Emp_ID")`. How can I also insert a random value, say 1 into Emp_ID(its the pk) at the same time? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave off the parentheses around the select, this is not a subselect.

**EDIT:**
For the second question in the comment (error: null value of ID column of target table):

Add the id to insert to your select list like this (assuming you want to use id `1`):

```
INSERT INTO Employee(ID, averageSalary, averageTax)
SELECT 1, AVG(Salary), AVG(Tax)
  FROM HrDeptEmployee 
 WHERE State = 'NY'
```